# How to perform calculations on queries in mysql that return multiple values

Tags: mysql

First query:

```
SELECT COUNT(sales.ucid) AS totalOutcomes
FROM sales
group by date(sales.saleDate)
```

Second query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS joinedOutcomes
FROM sales
JOIN calls 
ON sales.ucid = calls.call_id
group by date(sales.saleDate)
```

I now want to use the output from the second query and divide that by the output from the first query.
Can someone please help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Let's consider the first query in isolation. Does it not bother you that you have no idea which total belongs to which date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two queries.

```
SELECT t1.date, joinedOutcomes/totalOutcomes
FROM (
    SELECT date(sales.saleDate) AS date, COUNT(sales.ucid) AS totalOutcomes
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY date
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT date(sales.saleDate) AS date, COUNT(*) AS joinedOutcomes
    FROM sales
    JOIN calls ON sales.ucid = calls.call_id
    group by date
) AS t2 ON t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: it worked but I had to change the name of the variable from date to d1 and d2 as I got this error: Error Code: 1052. Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous. But thanks for your help!

Comment: I fixed it in a simpler way.